# Managing Oracle Synonyms

Tags: oracle, object, schema, synonym

I was reading this article:
[Managing Oracle Synonyms](http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/synonyms.htm)

Regarding the order of preference, when it come to resolving an object name to the actual object, it says:

1. Local objects will always be accessed first.
2. If a local object does not exist, the object with a private synonym will be accessed.
3. If a private synonym does not exist or the object does not exist, then the public synonym will be used.

I was wondering if the public objects are missing in this order somehow?

E.g. if user BOB queries

```
select * from FOOBAR
```

and there is no BOB.FOOBAR in dba_tables/views but PUBLIC.FOOBAR.

Does Oracle resolve it to PUBLIC.FOOBAR or will it check for synonyms first?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least up to 10g, PUBLIC is not a real user. You cannot create objects in the "Public schema":

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE public.foobar (id integer);

CREATE TABLE public.foobar (id integer)

ORA-00903: invalid table name

SQL> CREATE TABLE system.foobar (id integer);

Table created

SQL>
```

If you run this query:

```
SELECT object_name 
  FROM dba_objects 
 WHERE owner='PUBLIC' 
   AND object_type IN ('TABLE', 'VIEW');
```

You can answer the question about pre-defined tables/views in the PUBLIC "schema".

Comment: Well, you can create public synonyms, which are objects as well. I would be interested in:
1) can you create tables/views in the public schema?
2) are there any predefined tables/views in the public schema?

Comment: That's what I'm showing above. You cannot create a table in the public "schema".

Comment: See my updated answer where I address the predefined question.

Answer (score 10):

In your example, `FOOBAR` is almost certainly a public synonym.  There is no `PUBLIC` schema but `PUBLIC` is listed as the owner of a public synonym.

If I create a new public synonym

```
SQL> create public synonym pub_syn_emp
  2     for scott.emp;

Synonym created.
```

the owner of that synonym ends up being `PUBLIC`

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select object_name, owner, object_type
  2    from dba_objects
  3*  where object_name = 'PUB_SYN_EMP'
SQL> /

OBJECT_NAME          OWNER      OBJECT_TYP
-------------------- ---------- ----------
PUB_SYN_EMP          PUBLIC     SYNONYM
```

In addition, item #3 does not appear to be correct.  If there is a private synonym that points to a non-existent object and a public synonym that points to a valid object, the private synonym still takes precedence.  You'll just get an error when Oracle tries to resolve the private synonym to an actual object.

```
SQL> create synonym syn_emp for scott.no_such_table;

Synonym created.

SQL> create public synonym syn_emp for scott.emp;

Synonym created.

SQL> select * from syn_emp;
select * from syn_emp
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00980: synonym translation is no longer valid
```

Comment: Oh, so it's just synonyms that can have PUBLIC as a owner? As it seems that you cannot create any tables/views with a public owner, my question would be whether there are any predefined tables or views that have PUBLIC as a owner.

Comment: @Will - There are no predefined tables or views that are owned by the pseudo-schema `PUBLIC`.  There is a pseudo-role `PUBLIC` that is implicitly granted to all users that has some privileges granted to it mainly to grant execute access on various predefined packages to all users.